# How do I make use of CoffeeKup when writing jQuery

Tags: jquery, compiler-construction, coffeekup

I am quite new to web development and have started programming with node.js & express and using the coffeekup view engine. My problem is the following:

If I use the CoffeeKup view engine can I somehow insert coffeeKup code as a parameter to the jquery append method?!?
    So for example instead of writing `$('body').append('<p>')` I can write `$('body').append('p')` or `$('body').append(p)` or something similar. I want the compiler to somehow preprocess my coffee code...

Comment: This does not appear to have anything to do with coffeescript.  Please elaborate and retag if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AaronDufour coffeekup is markup language based on coffeescript, so it's indirectly related.

Answer (score 2):

There's examples of what you are trying to achieve in the examples/browser directory of the coffeekup source. Maurice calls your specific flavour of client-side (browser) coffeekup [creme](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup/tree/master/examples/browser/creme).

The gist of it is that you include coffeekup and coffeescript libraries and write your template in a js file or in a script element. The following is from the [creme/index.html](https://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup/blob/master/examples/browser/creme/index.html) file.

```
<script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script src="coffeekup.js"></script>

<script type="text/coffeescript">
  stooges = ['moe', 'larry', 'curly']

  $().ready ->
    codey = ->
      h2 'Template as a function'

      ul ->
        for guy in @stooges
          li guy

    $('body').append CoffeeKup.render(codey, stooges: stooges)
</script>
```